# Dist(B)+ Dist(A-B)

Tags: algorithm

A is a sequence of distinct elements,B is a subsequence of A,A-B is all the elments in A but not in B
Dist(A) = Sum|a(i)-a(i+1)| from i=1 to n-1
Find a subsequence  B such that Dist(B)+Dist(A-B) is minimum
I know this can be solved using dynamic programming but cant figure out how...
anyone with an answer???

Comment: nope...its a question that i came across in my exam today ....had no idea to solve it....was curious about how this could be solved :)

Comment: sorry i meant dist() ill edit it asap

Comment: Is dist here is a_{i} - a_{i-1} ?

Comment: dist(a) is the sum from i= 1 to n-1 of a[i]-a[i+1]

Comment: For example if A={1,2,3} dist(A)= (1-2)+(2-3)

Comment: Oh, sorry, the Dist(A) was truncated for me.. Can you please explain about B, given that A = {1,2,3}?

Comment: B is a subsequence of A ....for eg: {1,2} in the example we need to find an optimal subsequence B(of A) which would minimize the value of Dist(B)+Dist(A-B), hope this helps

Comment: Rachit, the last question, for all elements of A, is |(a_{i} - a_{i-1}| == const?

Comment: no they are all integers so the difference wont be a constant

Answer (score 0):

Let us add one element at a time, and let us label B and A-B such that the last element added is in B.  If we N elements in A we need to keep track of N sets B_i such that B_i is the least cost solution where the last element in A-B is a_i (the set B_0 is the set A, so that A-B is empty).  When we add a_n we update the cost of each of the B_i by adding |a_n + a_{n-1}| and let B_{n-1} be the set (A - B_k) + {a_n}  where k is is has the minimum |a_n - a_k|.